# Converting mysql unix time and using BETWEEN

Tags: php, mysql, time, unix-timestamp

I have a  form where the user can choose 2 dates, hit submit, and the form returns tickets that were created between those 2 dates.

The dates from the form are in this format: **mm/dd/year**

The dates in mysql are being saved as unix timestamps.

After the submit, I'm converting the date format like this:

```
  $from = $_POST['from']
  $to = $_POST['to'];
  $from = date("Y/m/d",strtotime($_GET['from']));
  $to = date("Y/m/d",strtotime($_GET['to']));
```

So that $from is something like **year/mm/dd**

My query is:

```
$get = mysql_query("SELECT id FROM tickets WHERE date_created BETWEEN UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$from') AND UNIX_TIMESTAMP('$to')");
```

This works fine, my problem is, when the from and to dates are equal, meaning the user wants to see tickets for one day only.  Is it still possbile to use the same query somehow? Or how do I modify the query?

Comment: What I'd do is explicitly set the time on $from and $to to be 00:00:00 and 23:59:59 respectively, can't recall the PHP for it OTOMH

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not do...

```
$from = date("Y-m-d 00:00:00",strtotime($_GET['from']));
$to = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59",strtotime($_GET['to']));
```

Also, be careful as you're mixing `$_GET` and `$_POST`. MySQL has built in date/time functions that can handle this type of conversion. It would be better if you used binded parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Change your $to and $from to use the first second of the day and the last second of the day:

```
$from = date("Y-m-d 0:0:0", strtotime($_GET['from']));
$to = date("Y-m-d 23:59:59", strtotitme($_GET['to']));
```